# Why $\mathop{var}(u^T B u) = 2\sigma^4 \sum_{i \neq j} b_{ij}^2+ (\mathbb{E}[U^4] -\sigma^4)\sum_i b_{ii}^2$?

Tags: linear-algebra, probability, statistics

I have the following statement that I am trying to reproduce the proof of it.

> Let $B$ be a $n \times n$ symmetric matrix and let $u = (u_1, \dots, u_n)^T$ be a vector of $n$ independent samples forma random variable
> $U$ with zero mean and variance $\sigma^2$. Also, we have that $$\mathbb{E}[u^T B u] = \sigma^2 \mathop{tr}(B).\tag{1}$$ Then we have: $$\mathop{var}(u^T B
> u) = 2\sigma^4 \sum_{i \neq j} b_{ij}^2+ (\mathbb{E}[U^4]
> -\sigma^4)\sum_i b_{ii}^2\tag{2}$$

The proof I have is:

> Proof:
>
> $\begin{align}\mathop{var}(u^T B u) = \mathbb{E}[(u^T B u)^2] &=
>  \mathbb{E}\left[ \left(\sum_{i,j}u_i b_{ij} u_j\right)\left(\sum_{r,s}
>  u_r b_{rs} u_d\right)\right] \tag{3}\\ &= \mathbb{E}\left[\sum_{i,j}
> \sum_{r,s} b_{ij}b_{rs} u_i u_j u_r u_s \right] \tag{4}\\ & =
>  2\sigma^4 \sum_{i \neq j} b_{ij}^2 + \sigma^4 \sum_{i \neq j}
>  b_{ii}b_{jj} + \mathbb{E}[U^4]\sum_i b_{ii}^2 \tag{5}\end{align}$
>
> Since $$\left(\mathbb{E}[u^T B u]\right)^2 \stackrel{(1)}{=} \sigma^4
> (\mathop{tr}(B))^2 = \sigma^4 \sum_{i,j}b_{ii} b_{jj}\tag{6}$$ it
> follows that $(2)$ holds.

I am trying to understand how $(5)$ is obtained from $(4)$ and finally how $(6)$ is used in $(5)$ to get $(2)$. Could you please someone cast some light? Any help is highly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- If $i=j=r=s$, then the addend is $b_{ii}^2 u_i^4$, whose expectation is $b_{ii} E[U^4]$. This is the last term in (5).
- If $i=j$ and $r=s$, then the addend is $b_{ii} b_{rr} u_i^2 u_r^2$, whose expectation is $b_{ii} b_{rr} E[u_i^2 u_r^2] = b_{ii} b_{rr} E[U^2]^2 = b_{ii} b_{rr} \sigma^4$. This is the second term in (5).
- If $i=r$ and $j=s$, then the addend is $b_{ij}^2 u_i^2 u_j^2$ which (by similar reasoning as the previous case) has expectation $b_{ij}^2 \sigma^4$. This contributes to the first term of (5).
- If $i=s$ and $j=r$, then by the same reasoning the addend has expectation $b_{ij}^2 \sigma^4$. This contributes to the first term of (5) (i.e. this case and the previous case account for the factor of $2$ in front of the first term of (5)).
- In all other cases, there is one of $i,j,r,s$ that is different from the other three. If for example $i$ is different from $j,r,s$, then when computing the expectation of that addend, you will obtain a factor of $E[u_i]$ which is zero, and makes the whole term zero.

  - Example: if $j=r=s$ and $i \ne j$, then the expectation of the addend is $b_{ij} b_{jj} E[u_i u_j^3] = b_{ij} b_{jj} E[u_i] E[u_j^3]=0$ because $E[u_i]=0$.

---

The left-hand side of (3) should be $\text{var}(u^\top Bu) + (E[u^\top B u])^2$ instead of $\text{var}(u^\top B u)$. After making this correction, you can then combine (5) with (6) to get (2).

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Please give some time to process.

Comment: Is it possible to provide more details in the example you give in last bullet? It would be very helpful If I could see how the sums are manipulated and how $E[u_i]$ appears in the calculations. Thanks again.

Comment: @darkmoor Updated my answer

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Could you please give more details about your last comment? I do not see why $\text{var}(u^\top Bu) + (E[u^\top B u])^2 = \mathbb{E}\left[ \left(\sum_{i,j}u_i b_{ij} u_j\right)\left(\sum_{r,s}
 u_r b_{rs} u_d\right)\right]$.

Comment: @darkmoor $\text{Var}(u^\top B u) + (E[u^\top B u])^2 = E[(u^\top B u)^2]$ by the definition of variance. Then the right-hand side can be expanded into the product of double sums.